# Telemetry track event (custom Events) in bot composer are missing in application insights

Tags: botframework, azure-application-insights, bot-framework-composer

I'm trying to track the telemetry event by adding debugging option -> emit a telemetry trace event.
[TelemetryEvent in botcomposer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qVIRl.png) (Please refer this image)

When I use to check the logs in application insights, I able to see the logs but sometimes it is not getting logged.

Composer version - V2.1.1
Microsoft.bot.builder version - 4.15.0
.Net version - netcoreapp3.1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Custom Telemetry from Bot Framework Composer not being consistently logged in Application Insights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73141766/custom-telemetry-from-bot-framework-composer-not-being-consistently-logged-in-ap)

Answer (score 0):

There are two versions of the composer we can implement.

**Composer V1x:**

The composer needs to have two additional settings to solve the inconsistent log hitting.

[image]

**`logPersonalInformation`** and **`logActivities`** are the two things which need to be updated.

**Composer V2x:**

[image]

For Composer version 2, we need to update the same, but based on the version, we need to use the same updates in the composer file.