# Custom Telemetry from Bot Framework Composer not being consistently logged in Application Insights

Tags: botframework, azure-application-insights, bot-framework-composer

Currently building out a bot in Bot Framework Composer and deploying it on the Teams client. I suddenly am having issues since last week where my custom telemetry ("telemetry - track action") is no longer showing any results in Application Insights. The few that did also only save one property and not the others (see image below). Other events (LUIS, bot message received, etc) all show up in real time and correctly.

[The only telemetry event that saved in the past week (there should be at least 10 saved), with only one property logged](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mXkiQ.png)

[The telemetry event and its properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EwXLm.png)

Comment: What version of runtime sdk are you using? if greater than 4.15.0, there is a known bug telemetry does not seem to work inside for each loop and child dialogs. The PR has been created here https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/pull/6391

Comment: I'm using .Net Core Runtime version 3.1.27.

Comment: sorry, I'm referring to [Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Adaptive.Runtime](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Adaptive.Runtime/). You can view this package version in Composer: `Package Mangager -> Instelled `

Comment: Ex; https://i.imgur.com/h3xyJF8.png

Comment: Can you please verify if you have this package installed  `Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Adaptive.Runtime` and greater than `4.15.0`?

Comment: Yes, I do have that package installed and it is version 4.16.0 (which is greater)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known bug in [Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Adaptive.Runtime](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Adaptive.Runtime/) version `greater than 4.15.0`

There is a pull request for this issue and most likely will be fixed in next release of [botbuilder-dotnet](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet)

PR https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/pull/6391

A workaround for now is to downgrade the Adaptive.Runtime package to [4.14.0](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/releases/tag/4.14.0)

To learn how to downgrade packages in .NET, here is doc to [Install and manage packages in Visual Studio using the NuGet Package Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/install-use-packages-visual-studio)